# Error running Google App Engine quickstart : POM for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.9.24 is missing

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Any help getting me past this error would be appreciated. Google searches don't seem to turn up any helpful results. 
I am on a Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite and using the Java 1.7.0_71 with Maven 3.3. Maven was installed via HomeBrew.

To get an introduction of Google App Engine, I followed the instructions for the quickstart from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction and reach the page instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code without issue.
After creating the **guestbook.jsp** file and running `mvn appengine:devserver` I get the following build failure.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.9.24 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.24: Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.24 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:1.9.24 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 4.3 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 2.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.435 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-22T21:10:29-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/nissandookeran/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.9.24 of the Appengine Maven Plugin [hasn't been deployed to Maven Central yet](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-maven-plugin/), for whatever reason.  Probably the easiest thing to do is to open your pom.xml, find the `<version>` of `appengine-maven-plugin` that it's using, and make it use `1.9.23` instead of `${appengine.version}` or `1.9.24` or whatever it's using.

Answer (score 1):

If it is due to a new version you can try also to run `mvn appengine:devserver -U`

Comment: [Official reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven): If there is a failure indicating that the App Engine Maven plugin is missing, this could be due to the fact that a new version was recently pushed to the Maven repo. To remedy this, invoke Maven with the -U option: mvn appengine:devserver -U

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following in the pom file

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
           <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.48</version>
        </plugin>
```